# Why should get the Binary response when uploading wave file to server using AFNetworking library

Tags: ios, iphone, afnetworking

I have a requirement where i am uploading a wave file on server and server gives me back the URL of that file.

I have used this Codes..

```
- (void)callUploadWS
{
NSString *vidURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"alarm" ofType:@"wav"];
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:vidURL]];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://6.6.237.190"];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
//  NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"Romantic.jpg"], 0.5);
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/recorder/convert.php" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:videoData name:@"file" fileName:@"speech.wav" mimeType:@"audio/vnd.wave"];
}];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
}];
// [httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];

[operation  setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {NSLog(@"Success : %@",responseObject);}
                                  failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                      NSLog(@"error: %@",  operation.responseString);

                                      NSLog(@"error: %@", error.userInfo);
                                  }];
[operation start];
}
```

Its uploading file and giving me this response...

`Success : <7b226669 6c65223a 22687474 703a5c2f 5c2f352e 392e3233 372e3135 305c2f72 65636f72 6465725c 2f75706c 6f61645c 2f353237 32336564 32366531 63662e77 6176227d>`

But it should give response like this..

```
{
file: "http://6.6.237.190/recorder/upload/52723ef52972d.wav"
}
```

why this gives binary response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert the responseObject to NSString like this

```
NSString *responseString=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:[responseObject bytes]];
```

Comment: Thats done it. But a question why should i do that? I have used AFNetworking for my text download and upload but never used this.

Comment: I don't know how you are using it, but I always use in this way

Answer (score 0):

@Gagan Kumar has given really nice answer but its half code. It will convert your json response to a String.
So you are not be able to get the dictionary from that and not able to parse the file URL. For doing that you have to reserialize the String to json using this code..

```
NSString *responseString=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:[responseObject bytes]];

NSError *e = nil;
NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];
if (e) {
      NSLog(@"error : %@",e);
}else{
      NSLog(@"JSON : %@",JSON);
}
```

This will return the json object which will be parsable.
Hope it help.